# CSS3 marquee not sliding in Chrome and Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera, marquee

I am quite new in CSS3. W wanted to do a simple marquee but i dont want to use  tag and JS/JQuery. Perfect sollution for me is marquee in CSS3 but it's not sliding in Chrome and Opera (in Firefox and IE works fine). What am I writed wrong?
This is a simple example of my code:
http://pastebin.com/fG8As6i7

Answer (score 2):

Chrome seems to have abandoned support for the CSS3 marquee stuff. I am using my Raspberry Pi to display stock data in a CSS3 marquee, and that has been working fine - recently, I discovered that on my laptop (with latest Chrome) the page is no longer working. When I check in developer tools, I also see that the marquee properties like (-webkit-)marquee-style are now unrecognized ("Unknown property name"). My Raspberry Pi has an older version of Chrome in which this still works. As an alternative, use the  element, which seems to be okay in Chrome currently (v32 Beta). However, it probably won't last. The WhatWG standard already declares it as obsolete: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html
The only solution that will work in the long run is based on JavaScript and/or a custom CSS animation (for example with keyframes).

EDIT: Sorry, didn't read enough... Apparently, you're actually already trying to get it done with CSS animations.